# Regex match after numbers before double underscore

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract substrings that start after a number and before a double underscore. Below you see two test strings and the expected output after `->`.

```
'1234514 TEST STRING__blabla3452b' -> 'TEST STRING'
'16275653 TEST_STRING__bl67abla3452b' -> 'TEST_STRING'
```

The regex I came up with so far: `(?:^|\n)\d+([^__]+)` only  returns  the first but not the second output as the second underscore is not recognised. I tried to escape the underscores but that did not work. Any help would be very much apprecciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `re.search(r'\d+(.+)__', text, re.S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d+\s*(.*?)(?=__)
\d\s+(.*?)(?=__)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/wuBEcM/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/wuBEcM/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=__)` - a location immediately followed with `__`.

Comment: Why not just `^\d+\s*(.*?)__`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland To make it clear that `([^__]+)` is not the right way to match and exclude a multi-character sequence.